# FAB Behavior when showing CardView (Up & Down)

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I want to show a CardView as prompt like in Material Guidelines Specs: 
https://www.google.com/design/spec/growth-communications/onboarding.html#onboarding-quickstart

Here is the link to the image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AxvX.png)

I've changed the behavior of the FAB Button like this and set to the .xml file:

```
public class FABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public FABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof CardView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
        float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My .xml file look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.nearme.client.activities.fragments.ScannerFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:title="@string/title_scanner"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/fragment_scanner_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvBluetooth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Prueba" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="com.nearme.client.utils.FABBehavior"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

And the click listener of the FAB Button is this:

```
View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == fab) {
            if (cardBluetooth.isShown()) {
                cardBluetooth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else
                cardBluetooth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is when the CardView's visibility goes GONE the FAB button remain up in its position.

How can I update the position of the FAB when the CardView is GONE?

Even if I set the CardView in the CoordinatorLayout dinamically and remove it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was that `onDependentViewChanged`from `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` only get called when the dependent view have changed its position. But I only was changing its visibility so it didnt get called.

Now in the `onClick` I add to the view and remove it:

```
View.OnClickListener onClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == fab) {
            if (cardBluetooth.isShown()) {
                coordinatorLayout.removeView(cardBluetooth);
            } else
                coordinatorLayout.addView(cardBluetooth);
        }
    }
};
```

And in `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` I added:

```
@Override
public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    child.animate().translationY(0);
    child.setTranslationY(0);
}
```

And this is the result:
[GIF of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFC4E.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Change the method ***layoutDependsOn*** method according to this:

```
@Override
public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
    return dependency instanceof CardView && onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
}
```

Otherwise, the fab button is going to move up only the first time it gets clicked.